# Why updating time is so important for a web server like nginx?

Tags: time, nginx, webserver

[image]

As you can see,every time a signal is received,nginx will first of all `update time`,why is `time` a big deal for web servers?

Answer (score 2):

nginx uses the time for [rate limiting](http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/http/ngx_http_write_filter_module.c#L212), among other things (like logging).

Implementing good rate limiting is probably the main reason to keep the value as up-to-date as possible, though.

Answer (score 2):

In the event-driven programming, timer is an important thing which used to process timeout event etc.

So nginx must update time at first to keep timer working correctly.